# Plane flying perp against wind problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

Plane is 300miles E of chicago and it leaves flying east at 500mph. Wind is blowing 50mph south.
What is planes ground speed?
Where is plane 0.6 hours later when pilot expects to land in cleveland?

This is how I set it up:
I want PG, which is plane speed relative to ground
W = wind, P = plane, G = ground

(V_x)_PG = (V_x)_PW + (V_x)_WG

(V_y)_PG = (V_y)_PW + (V_y)_WG

So now Im filling in the values and it doenst look right, so I wanted to check this preliminary step

(V_x)_PG = (V_x)_PW + (V_x)_WG --> 500mph = (V_x)_PW + 0mph

(V_y)_PG = (V_y)_PW + (V_y)_WG --> 0mph = (V_y)_PW + (-50mph)

I think (V_x)PW should also be 500mph and (V_y)PW should = +50mph to make the equations correct, but the 2 equations are not telling me anything I didnt already know from the question stem, which is what is totally confusing me.
thanks for any help

Comment: Draw a picture and update your question.